# Odd digits in a number

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to go through each digit in a integer number and return true if all digits are odd and false if even

I was able to develop typical odd and even check but this looks the whole number not every digit, how do I check every digit and return True if odd?

```
def odigits(n):
  new_list=[n]


for item in new_list:
    if item%2==0:
      return False
    else:
      return True
```

e.g Input 71358

```
Output = False (since 8 is even digit)
```

Comment: What if you could isolate each digit from the number using arithmetic operations. Hint: `n % 10 = last digit of n` and `n // 10 gives you the rest of the digits.`

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, but this is not a duplicate of the question you linked, that does not go into digit extraction :)

Comment: @anand_v.singh: Yes, it does. Read the posted answer., which explains how the poster can figure out the answer to their own homework ;:-) But you're right, it's probably not a suitable duplicate, so I've removed my close vote.

Answer (score 2):

This will sort you out.

```
def allOdd(num):
  while(num!=0):
    if (num%10)%2 == 0:
      return False
    num = int(num/10)
  return True
```

Answer (score 1):

In the below code, n is the integer number you would input.

```
while n>0:
    num=n%10
    if num%2==0:
    return False
    n=n/10
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the comments, I was able to convert the argument to list and string and go through each

def only_odd_digits(n):

new_list = [int(d) for d in str(n)]

for i in new_list:

```
random=0

if (i % 2)==0:

  return False
  random=1
  break

if random != 1:

return True
```